# Cassandra composite key using datastax java driver

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I'm new to Cassandra and I'm trying to evaluate it for my model. I'm testing with CQL3 and Cassandra 2.0

Let's assume I have the following domain model

```
public class CompositeSample1 {

  private String id;

  private List<ChildT1> childrenT1;

  private List<ChildT2> childrenT2;

  private String rootAttr1;

//getters setters omitted for brevity
}

public class ChildT1 {

  private String key;

  private String attr1;

  private String attr2;
//getters setters omitted for brevity
}

public class ChildT2 {

  private String key;

  private String attrA;

  private String attrB;

//getters setters omitted for brevity
}
```

So I want to store the above model in Cassandra in a single row with partition key being CompositeSample1.id. The children from the 2 relationships I want to store them as composite columns

id, rootAttr1, childT1|1 {attr1, attr2}, childT1|2 {attr1, attr2} .. childT2|1 {attrA, attrB}, childT2|2 {attrA, attrB}..

I've tried the following:

Created the schema with the following code:

```
session.execute(String.format("CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS %s WITH replication " +
                            "= {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':3};", DbContext.DATABASE_NAME));

      session.execute("USE "+DbContext.DATABASE_NAME);


      session.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS compositeSample1 (id uuid, rootAttr1 text, childT1Key text, childT1Attr1 text, , childT1Attr2 text "+
", childT2Key text, childT2AttrA text, childT2AttrB text, PRIMARY KEY ( (id), childT1Key, childT2Key))");
```

Tried to insert the following model instance

```
CompositeSample1 compositeSample1 = new CompositeSample1();
    compositeSample1.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    compositeSample1.setRootAttr1("A380");
    compositeSample1.setChildrenT1(new ArrayList<ChildT1>());
    compositeSample1.setChildrenT2(new ArrayList<ChildT2>());

    for (int i=1;i<10; i++)
    {
      ChildT1 child1 = new ChildT1();
      child1.setKey("childT1|"+i);
      child1.setAttr1("T1_1_"+i);
      child1.setAttr2("T1_2_"+i);
      compositeSample1.getChildrenT1().add(child1);

      ChildT2 child2 = new ChildT2();
      child2.setKey("childT1|"+i);
      child2.setAttrA("T2A"+i);
      child2.setAttrB("T2B"+i);
      compositeSample1.getChildrenT2().add(child2);
    }

    dbContext.createCompositeSample1(compositeSample1);


where the code for createCompositeSample1 is:
public void createCompositeSample1(CompositeSample1 compositeSample1) {
    if (createCompositeSample1 == null)
         createCompositeSample1 = session.prepare("INSERT INTO " + DbContext.DATABASE_NAME + ".compositeSample1(id, childT1Key, childT2Key, rootAttr1) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");

    if (createCompositeSample1ChildT1 == null)
      createCompositeSample1ChildT1 = session.prepare("INSERT INTO " + DbContext.DATABASE_NAME + ".compositeSample1(id, childT1Key, childT2Key, childT1Attr1, childT1Attr2) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");


    if (createCompositeSample1ChildT2 == null)
      createCompositeSample1ChildT2 = session.prepare("INSERT INTO " + DbContext.DATABASE_NAME + ".compositeSample1(id, childT1Key, childT2Key, childT2AttrA, childT2AttrB) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
    BoundStatement boundStatementParent = new BoundStatement(createCompositeSample1);

    getSession().execute(boundStatementParent.bind(UUID.fromString(compositeSample1.getId()), null, null, compositeSample1.getRootAttr1()));

    BoundStatement boundStatementChildT1 = new BoundStatement(createCompositeSample1ChildT1);
    for(ChildT1 childT1 : compositeSample1.getChildrenT1()){
      getSession().execute(boundStatementChildT1.bind(UUID.fromString(compositeSample1.getId()), childT1.getKey(), null, childT1.getAttr1(), childT1.getAttr2()));
    }

    BoundStatement boundStatementChildT2 = new BoundStatement(createCompositeSample1ChildT2);
    for(ChildT2 childT2 : compositeSample1.getChildrenT2()){
      getSession().execute(boundStatementChildT2.bind(UUID.fromString(compositeSample1.getId()), null, childT2.getKey(), childT2.getAttrA(), childT2.getAttrB()));
    }
  }
```

But I'm getting the following error

com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid null value for clustering key part childt1key

My goals are:

1. To prove that I can insert the CompositeSample1 without any children
2. Add children to any of the 2 relationships to ongoing

Can someone pinpoint what I'm doing wrong or haven't understood properly?

Thank you

Comment: Please try after changing your primaty key part do following

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your primary key part, there is no meaning of making composite partition key with only single column (in this case you have only id column as a part of composite partition key), create table as mention below.

```
session.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS compositeSample1 (id uuid, rootAttr1 text, childT1Key text, childT1Attr1 text, , childT1Attr2 text "+
", childT2Key text, childT2AttrA text, childT2AttrB text, PRIMARY KEY (id, childT1Key, childT2Key))");
```

And you can insert an empty string instead of null values, like given below

```
BoundStatement boundStatementParent = new BoundStatement(createCompositeSample1);

        session.execute(boundStatementParent.bind(UUID.fromString(compositeSample1.getId()), StringUtils.EMPTY, StringUtils.EMPTY,
                compositeSample1.getRootAttr1()));

        BoundStatement boundStatementChildT1 = new BoundStatement(createCompositeSample1ChildT1);
        for (ChildT1 childT1 : compositeSample1.getChildrenT1())
        {
            session.execute(boundStatementChildT1.bind(UUID.fromString(compositeSample1.getId()), childT1.getKey(),
                    StringUtils.EMPTY, childT1.getAttr1(), childT1.getAttr2()));
        }

        BoundStatement boundStatementChildT2 = new BoundStatement(createCompositeSample1ChildT2);
        for (ChildT2 childT2 : compositeSample1.getChildrenT2())
        {
            session.execute(boundStatementChildT2.bind(UUID.fromString(compositeSample1.getId()), StringUtils.EMPTY,
                    childT2.getKey(), childT2.getAttrA(), childT2.getAttrB()));
        }
```

It should work for you.